# Is any way to get key name of Enum from package enum in python2?

Tags: python-2.7, enums

I've following problem. We've got legacy code from our clients, right now I'm trying to prepare tests for this code. In the code there is used **enum** from following [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum/) for python2. In tests I'm getting integer values which are behind this enumerations but I'd rather like to get key name instead of numeric value what is much more readable when tests fails.

I found something like this but this works only with python3 enum package: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes

In python2 we can of course use **enum34** which has attribute `.name` but there is nothing like this in mentioned above **enum** package. Since change from already used **enum** package to **enum34** will be painful I'd rather like to get somehow the key of the enum using old package. Do you know any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!